# Optimization When Objective Function Can Only Be Approximately Computed

Tags: optimization, graph-algorithm, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods

I have some graph algorithms that depend on a moderate number of parameters (say 2-6), and which don't always succeed in finding what they want (they want 'good enough' solutions to problems known to be hard, like `mincut/maxflow`). I also have a very large family of graphs that I'd like to use the algorithms on.

My current goal is to find the parameter values for which a given algorithm most often succeeds. Unfortunately, the only way I know how to calculate 'success' is to take a graph from my large family and actually run the algorithm. This has two problems: it is computationally expensive, and it gives only an approximation to my real objective function, the true percentage of graphs on which the algorithm succeeds.

The first isn't the end of the world; Nelder-Mead or something similar could work. Is there a variant of this algorithm which would work in my situation? I expect success probabilities far from 0 or 1.

Comment: Mincut/maxflow have precise solutions, what do you mean by "problems known to be hard"? Is it just that you have difficulty implementing them?

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, switched computers and don't have the ability to edit - this is the original poster. In response to Shahbaz, I made a mistake. I meant to say sparsest cut, which is NP complete. The actual problem I'm working on is, as is often the case, rather messier. I really just meant to say that there's no hope for a clean solution, but ended up saying the opposite by accident.